# Multiple vs single change of variable (in convolution)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)g(x-y)|\, dy\, dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)| |g(t)|\, dy\, dt=\|f\|_1\|g\|_1$$
This calculation appears in proving that $f*g\in L^1$. My textbook justifies the first equality by making the **multiple** change of variables $x\mapsto x-y=t$ and $y\mapsto y$ whose Jacobian is $1$. I assume that the second equality is by Fubini's theorem.

My question is why don't we apply Fubini's theorem to the first integral to get
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)g(x-y)|\, dy\, dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)g(x-y)|\, dx\, dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(y)|\, dy\int_\mathbb{R}|g(x-y)|\, dx=\|f\|_1\|g\|_1.$$
using a **single** change of variables (or translation invariance of the measure on $\mathbb{R}$)?

I am not claiming that the second calculation is shorter or easier than the first one; I just want to make sure that my reasoning is not flawed. Thanks!

Comment: yes, if everything is absolutely convergent (Fubini's theorem) then $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) g(x-y) dy) dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) (\int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x-y) dx)  dy  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) B  dy = AB$ with $B = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x) dx$ and $A = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x) dx$. but here I guess they assume only $f,g \in L^1$, not that $f,g \in L^1 \cap L^\infty$, so you have to be more careful, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ makes sense (has a Lebesgue integral or something like that), but not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty$

Comment: @user1952009 It is only assumed that $f, g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and the goal is proving that $f*g\in L^1$. So there is no assumption on boundedness. I'm not sure what you mean by the last part of your comment; do you want to say that Fubini's theorem may not be applicable, despite absolute convergence?